# Can not access dom elements that are inside template tag in FF and IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, polymer

I have an `angular(1.X)` project that uses `Polymer` components(It might be a bad practice to have `Angular 1.x` and `Polymer` together but I have no option). The code snippet of the Angular Template is -

```
   <template id="app" is="dom-bind">
   <polymer-component></polymer-component>
   <div style="position: absolute;z-index:-1; width: 100%; top: 70px;background-color: white;">
 <iframe id="ifrm">
                <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
  </iframe>
  </template>
```

Now, when I try accessing the *iframe* in the Controller like - `$document.find('#ifrm')[0];`  I get `null` in firefox and IE but this works well in Chrome.
How do solve this in Angular?

PS: I can access the iframe when I put the `<iframe></iframe>` tag out of the `<template></template>` tag using `$document.find('#ifrm')[0];`.

Comment: you can't access inner iframe elements... but you can call "parent" functions at iframe scripts... Could you code at iframe page?

Comment: Its just not with iFrame but I am not able access any element using `document.getElementBy..` in FF and IE.